# How to mention which ssh key to use in git?

Tags: git, ssh

I have 3 ssh keys in my git account. Windows (one generated with RSA and one generated with ED25519 ), Linux (one generated with RSA algo). All the three keys have different titles.

I am using git bash and all the commands are working fine in windows but in linux I am getting access denied. My guess is its trying to access windows key value pair in Linux which its not able to find. Is there a way I can mention which ssh key (exact title) to be used while performing some operations?

Comment: The name associated with a key is purely informative, what counts is what private/public key is used when you connect through ssh.

Answer (score 2):

On your Linux system, check what keys are present in your `~/.ssh/` folder, and what keys are configured to be used in your `~/.ssh/config`

You can view how ssh behaves using the `-v` option :

```
ssh -v git@your.git.server
```

Comment: I have only one rsa key for linux and i can see the corresponding public key. private key and known hosts files in my .ssh folder. However I dont have any .ssh/config file. Should I add one? If yes, what should be the content of it?

Comment: I tried the above command. Its showing the debug statements and its referring to the sshk key which I have set for windows. Thats why its not able to find the corresponding keys. How to make it refer to the one which I set for Linux?

Comment: Google for it : one example : https://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/

Comment: Thank you for this. Should be `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: fixed (better late than never :D)

Answer (score 0):

To select which ssh key to use with git basically you have two options:

1. through configuration:
   just type `git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i /your/ssh/key_not_public"`
2. through env variable:
   before typing your git command, you should export the correct env variable: `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /your/ssh/key_not_public"`

I assume you the operation your are tolking about are git related since it is in your question (which is not clear from your description).